Do different Prometheus metric naming conventions mean something?
I'm a Prometheus newbie, and I'm using it on Kubernetes through the Prometheus Operator.
I saw that lots of metrics that are scraped have been named according to Prometheus metric naming convention, i.e.: node_boot_time_seconds. In the other hand there are few rules that use a colon separator, as cluster:namespace:pod_memory:active:kube_pod_container_resource_requests.
Is it just a matter of different conventions used? Or does the different naming conveys something deeper?

This flummoxed me too when I started with Prometheus. The colons (:) in names identify this as a recording rule. See this explanation

And see On the naming of things
